# Apollo Server cannot use await outside of async function

Tags: node.js, async-await, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to setup Apollo server and am using `startStandaloneServer` method to start a server but it shows error that `await` cannot be used outside of `async` function.

I am using this website as reference [startStandaloneServer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/standalone/#startstandaloneserver) and this is my code.

```js
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';

import { typeDefs } from "./schema.js";
import db from "./_db.js";

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    games() { return db.games },
    reviews() { return db.reviews },
    authors() { return db.authors }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server); //I am getting an error here

console.log("Server started at port:", 4000);
```

This is my `package.json`. I have changed the `type` to `module`

```json
{
  "name": "Graphql",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "@apollo/server": "^4.10.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "glitch"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error clearly showed what is wrong here, you can't use `await` outside of `async` function. Instead you will have to use [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

Comment: This should work with top-level `await`. Make sure to use a recent nodejs version and execute the code as an ES module, not as a script or CommonJS module.

Comment: @LãNgọcHải I am aware that I can't use `await` outside of `async`. The website that I mentioned have used `await` outside and it works. My question is that why it doesn't work when I try to do it

Comment: @Bergi I have added `"type": "module",` in my `package.json` is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @VirajDoshi which website? i think you have a type/ pasted the wrong link into the post. Please check again.

Comment: @VirajDoshi nevermind i found the your website. `await` can be used on top level of a module, so does it work now after you changed the type or there is still an error?

Comment: @LãNgọcHải ohh sorry, I'll edit my question. No, it still doesn't work after changing `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

Comment: @VirajDoshi That should work. What version of `node` do you have installed?

Comment: @Bergi its `20.11.1`

Comment: @Bergi could you figure it out whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript you should change target to "ESNext" in tsconfig.json also with type set to "module" in package.json and it should work. That was my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate async function and create server init.

```
async function startApolloServer(server) {
   const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server);
   console.log(`Server started at ${url}`);
}

startApolloServer(server);
```